# How to change projection in geoplot

Tags: python, coordinate-system, matplotlib, geoplot

I have trouble printing a map in Austrian Lambert projection.
I use matplotlib and geoplot. It all works fine as long as the shapefile has WGS84 (epsg=4326), or if not is set to these CRS (using file.to_crs(epsg=4326)). If not, I get an empty picture.
I want to print a shapefile that actually is in Lambert projection in this projection.
Here the examples:
What I want:
[image]

What I get:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=Myfigsize)
ax.axis('off')
gplt.polyplot(
    grow_zones, ax=ax, facecolor="red", edgecolor="black", linewidth=0.5)

fig = plt.gcf()

plt.savefig(file_out+'test.pdf')

plt.close(fig)
```

How can I get the picture in its own projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is projection you meant: EPSG: 31287, (https://epsg.io/31287), then that particular projection is actually not compatible with `geoplot`.

As discussed [here](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/user_guide/Working_with_Projections.html), `geoplot` relies on Cartopy's projection list, listed here: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/crs/projections.html#

The specific projection you want is not listed. Defining a projection outside this list (e.g. using `Proj4`) is currently [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150913/construct-cartopy-crs-from-proj4-parameters) possible. However, you can try and experiment with the other projections that may be close to the one you are attempting to see. To do that, this is the code snippet you can implement prior to creating the figures (and adjusting the `projection` parameter accordingly):

```
import geoplot.crs as gcrs
gplt.polyplot(grow_zones, projection=gcrs.LambertConformal()) #for example
```